# Размер почтовых ящиков в Exchange Management Shell

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange

Хочу получить и посортировать по размеру все почтовые ящики "@test.com" на сервере name.local.

Используя подобную команду:

```
Get-Mailbox -Server name.local| Get-MailboxStatistics | where {$_.ObjectClass -eq “Mailbox”} | where-object {($_.EmailAddresses -like "*test.com*")} | Sort-Object TotalItemSize -Descending | ft @{label=”User”;expression={$_.DisplayName}},@{label=”Total Size (MB)”;expression={$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()}} -auto >> “c:\Temp\mbox_size.txt”
```

получаю пустой файл. Что я упустил в коде команды?

Результат выполнения команд:

1) Получаю размер всех почтовых ящиков на сервере, а не только с "@test.com":

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Server name.local | where {$_.ObjectClass -eq "Mailbox"} | Sort-Object TotalItemSize -Descending | ft @{label="User";expression={$_.DisplayName}},@{label="Total Size (MB)";expression={$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()}},@{label="Items";expression={$_.ItemCont}},@{label="Storage Limit";expression={$_.StorageLimitStatus}} -auto

User                        Total Size (MB) Items Storage Limit
----                        --------------- ----- -------------
T, S                         54075          NoChecking
G, D                         51800          NoChecking
B, G                         43087          BelowLimit
D, R                         42614          NoChecking
```

2) Получаю ящики "@test.com", но не могу получить их размер (добавляя @{label=”Total Size (MB)”;expression={$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()}})

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited  | Select-Object Name, PrimarySMTPAddress | Where-Object {($_.PrimarySMTPAddress -like "*test.com*")}

Name                                                        PrimarySmtpAddress                                         
----                                                        ------------------                                         
W, E                                                       E@test.com                                       
C, A                                                       A@test.com                                       
K, T                                                       T@test.com                                          
K, M                                                       M@test.com
```

Пробовал разные комбинации, но без успеха.

Comment: а покажите что выводит `Get-Mailbox -Server name.local| Get-MailboxStatistics | where {$_.ObjectClass -eq “Mailbox”} | where-object {($_.EmailAddresses -like "*test.com*")} | Sort-Object TotalItemSize -Descending` . сервака под рукой нет.

Comment: К сожалению, также пусто.

Comment: тогда удалите все до последней | пока что нибудь не будет. после приложите команду  и вывод к вопросу

Comment: приложил команду и вывод к вопросу

Comment: сейчас нету сервака. попробуй `Get-MailboxStatistics -Server 'testServer.com' ` подробнее [тут](http://practical365.com/exchange-server/reporting-mailbox-folder-sizes-with-powershell/)

Comment: Также получаю или размер всех ящиков, или только имена тех ящиков которые нужны, но без размера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось выполнить поставленную задачу с помощью кода:

```
Get-Mailbox | Where-Object {($_.PrimarySMTPAddress -like "*test.com*")} | Get-MailboxStatistics | Sort-Object TotalItemSize -descending | Select-Object DisplayName,@{name="MailboxSize";exp={$_.totalitemsize}} | Out-File c:\report.txt
```